# How to check php multidimensional array values are same or not?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My array is like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [con_id] => 44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [con_id] => 217
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [con_id] => 217
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [con_id] => 217
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [con_id] => 97
        )

)
```

I want to check all the `con_id` are the same then, return `true` or return `false`. Is there any built-in function in php for doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check count of [unique](http://php.net/array_unique) elements.

```
$array = array(array('con_id'=>44),array('con_id'=>44),);
$result = count(array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR))==1; 

var_dump($result);
```